# Spark on Yarn Failed to send RPC and Slave lost

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I want to deploy spark2.3.2 on Yarn, Hadoop2.7.3.
But when I run:

```
spark-shell
```

Always raise ERROR:

```
ERROR TransportClient:233 - Failed to send RPC 4858956348523471318 to /10.20.42.194:54288: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
...
ERROR YarnScheduler:70 - Lost executor 1 on dc002: Slave lost
```

Both dc002 and dc003 will raise ERRORs `Failed to send RPC` and `Slave lost`.

I have one master node and two slave node server. They all are:
`CentOS Linux release 7.5.1804 (Core)` with 40 cpu and 62.6GB memory and 31.4 GB swap.

My `HADOOP_CONF_DIR`:

```
export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=/home/spark-test/hadoop-2.7.3/etc/hadoop
```

My `/etc/hosts`:

```
10.20.51.154 dc001
10.20.42.194 dc002
10.20.42.177 dc003
```

In Hadoop and Yarn Web UI, I can see both dc002 and dc003 node, and I can run simple mapreduce task on yarn in hadoop.
But when I run `spark-shell` or `SparkPi` example program by

```
./spark-submit --deploy-mode client --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi spark-2.3.2-bin-hadoop2.7/examples/jars/spark-examples_2.11-2.3.2.jar 10
```

, ERRORs always raise.
I really want to why those errors happened.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this problem by changing the `yarn-site.xml` conf file:

```
<property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.pmem-check-enabled</name>
    <value>false</value>
</property>

<property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.vmem-check-enabled</name>
    <value>false</value>
</property>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this parameter in you code-

```
spark.conf.set("spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled", "false")
```

Secondly while doing spark submit, define parameters like --executor-memory and --num-executors
sample:

```
spark2-submit --executor-memory 20g --num-executors 15 --class com.executor mapping.jar
```